# Continuing activity indicator in the Android's notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have a [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) with continuing activity indicator. The problem is that when the application is terminated by user, the indicator is still running. Is there some sort of "OnExit" method what is called when the application is closed, so that I can delete the notification from the notification panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/LdIljkPFack), there is no such method right now, as far as I know. I don't think you could rely on `application.onTerminate()`, so you'd better change your logic to use a service that creates and removes notification on it's lifecycle methods.